# use a last row calculation from a destination workbook as a row value range in a source workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Excuse my VBA ignorance..  I'm trying to automate an export of selected columns from a source workbook, which is populated continuously from a web-based source.  The destination workbook is needed for a record-keeping process. My problem is that a simple copy/paste will write over the cells in the destination workbook.  I've got code to calculate the last row used in my destination sheet, which I'm calling `lastrow`.  I'd like to use the `lastrow` as the row value so that I can copy from the source workbook beginning at the `lastrow` calculated from my destination workbook. The goal is to continuously add rows to my destination sheet from my source sheet, without writing over the existing rows of data.

```
Sub johnson()
    Dim wb As Workbook, wbTemp As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsTemp As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Open("F:\Projects\Ballot Reconciliation\DRAFT 2014     
    Reconciliation spreadsheet.xlsx")
    Set wsTemp = wbTemp.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'calculate last row having been used in the destination worksheet

    lastrow = wsTemp.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'use lastrow as the input row value for the copy out of the source worksheet.

    ws.Range("A(lastrow):A5000").Copy wsTemp.Range("B" & lastrow)

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    wbTemp.Close savechanges:=True
    Set wb = Nothing: Set wbTemp = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing: Set wsTemp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to calculate the last row on the record-keeping sheet as well and set up your `.Copy` action using that as the destination (rather than the last row from the source sheet):

```
Dim LastTargetRow As Long

'... do stuff

With wsTemp
    LastTargetRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
End With

'... do stuff
```

Then you can simply copy to `wsTemp.Range("B" & LastTargetRow)`.

Something nit-picky here, but potentially a saver of headaches further down the line... What do you think about adjusting your variable names to better indicate what they are up to? I might pick `Source` instead of `ws` to describe the source data sheet, `DestBook` for the destination workbook and `Dest` for the destination sheet...

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here, but this is what I did: `ws.Range("A" & lastrow & ":" & "A5000").Copy wsTemp.Range("B" & lastrow)`.  It worked!